# Ensuring that onLoad of an IFRAME doesn't execute too soon

Tags: javascript, dom, onload

I just discovered that the source of my issues is that the parent HTML makes calls to controls in a child IFRAME **but** is too quick about that and, sometimes, the super *onLoad* attempts to do so **before** the sub *onLoad* had a chance to add stuff to the DOM.

What can I do about it?

I've tried to set up some kind of feed-back from *onLoad* in the child. Failed miserably with so many strange errors that they can be summarized by *dude, just please don't*.

I've tried to set up a delayer, which is ugly of epic proportions **and** not 100% reliable.

EDIT:

In `onload` I do this:

```
var stuff = getReferenceToStuff();
var someDiv = stuff.contentWindow.document.getElementById("someDiv");
someDiv.className = "classy";
```

The problem is that **sometimes** the reference *someDiv* is *null* and sometimes (often when I reload the page by F5), it points to the correct element. I know it's because the contents of the IFRAME are a bit slower.

So my questions is this. How can I ensure that *onload* is postponed until the embedded IFRAME component's *onload* ensures that it's been loaded and all the components are there?

Comment: Without the code answering to the question would be only guessing. Please add the relevant codes to your post.

Comment: @Teemu What code would you like to see? The JS with *window.onload* that refers to the IFRAME? I'm not clear on which part that'd be relevant here. I need to know how I can ensure that all the controls of an IFRAME are loaded **before** I write things to them from the containing parent DOM.

Comment: The codesnippets where attaching "super listener" and  "sub listener" and some example for populating `iframe` would be nice. Maybe also a link to your page...

Comment: Can there be a pure html5 solution?

Comment: @Teemu It's an internal solution so I can't provide a link, sorry. Passwords and legal stuff, you know. The code snippets, I'm still not clear what good they will do for **my** question but I'm updating the question. Have a look.

Comment: @closure I'm not sure. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

When using `window.onload` *all* content of the `body`, including content of the `iframe`s and all other resources like images, should be loaded *before* the `onload` is fired. However, some browsers have had problems with timing on firing `onload`, i.e. different browsers trigger the event in different stage of page parsing.

If you're using `DOMContentLoaded` or jQuery's `$(document).ready()`, only the HTML of the main page is loaded, but some resources are still under work (including `iframe`'s content loading). I'm not aware what happens if you attach an inline listener for the `iframe` element itself.

If there's timing problems, maybe not trigger the function needing `iframe` reference in main window at all. Instead invoke that function in main window in `irame`'s `window.onload`. But even this won't tackle the problem, if you're using some asynchronous technique to populate the `iframe`. In this case you need to invoke the function in main window after all requests have been completed.

(Now you maybe also know, what are the codesnippets I'd like to see in your post : ) ).

Comment: Haha, **now** I get it. And you're right on when it comes to the asynchronous part. In the IFRAME I make a *XDomainRequest* call to fetch data elsewhere. I'll just put the execution of the method as the last statement in the *onready* there. Tada! I didn't know I could execute a method in the parent, though. Is it just *window.parent.doPoo()*? I think I tried that once but failed...

Comment: `window.parent.doPoo()` should work when the timing is correct, i.e. all information needed have been loaded in `iframe` and `doPoo()` is available in main window ofcourse.

Comment: How can I ensure that the timing is correct? Is it guaranteed by the script executor? (Also, it was supposed to be **doFoo()**. Now, it sounds a bit yacky.)

Comment: Haha, I don't know what "Poo" means, just copied it from your comment : ). Timing is correct when all asynchronous tasks are completed, and the main window function is defined. `head` section maybe the best place for it, so it'll be there when invoked. (Just googled "poo", it's yacky for sure...)

Answer (score 1):

The `onLoad` event isn't always working correctly on `document`. It works correctly on each element though.

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'),
    counter = 0,
    max = iframes.length;

[].forEach.call(iframes, iLoaded);

function iLoaded() {
    if (++counter === max) {
        callback();
    }
}

function callback() {
    // All the iframes are loaded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions to your problem:

1. If you are on HTML5, use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage). Just message from iFrame to the parent in the onload of iFrame. Parent should register handler in `<script>` tag, that appears before iFrame.
2. Add a callback function to window in the '' tag before iFrame. This function is called by iFrame when it's load is complete. Here is the basic template.

Here is the sample template:

```
  <script>
  window.iframeCallback = function(message) {

    // first clear the temp function we added to the window
    // It is a bad practice to corrupt the global namespace
    delete window.iframeCallback;

    // you do your work here

  };
  </script>

  ..
  ..

  <!-- iFrame should appear after the above script-->
  <iframe/>
```